# Navigation Menu CSS not linking

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, navigationbar

I am working on a web application with multiple pages, and am working on styling a navigation bar for my users to go through the different pages.  However, when I try to link the navigation bar to the pages, something is going wrong.  When I preview the code, clicking on the different tabs doesn't redirect me to the corresponding pages.  Attached is my code so far.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #333;
        }

        li {
            float: left;
        }

        li a {
            display: block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        li a:hover {
            background-color: #111;
        }

        li a:active {
            background-color: #51014d;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="home">
        <h1>Welcome!</h1></div>
    <div id="contact" style="visibility: hidden">
        <h2>you can reach me 
        at:</h2></div>

    <style>
        #home {
            background-color: honeydew;
        }
    </style>
    <style>
        #contact {
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
    </style>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to make the navigation menu link to different pages of my website (for example, they can go to "contact", and view information regarding that topic). However, the links with this code aren't working. When I click on the different tabs, it does not show the corresponding page.  How do I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "something is going wrong"? Can you tell us what you're trying to achieve and what is the expected result?

Comment: I am trying to make the navigation menu link to different pages of my website (for example, they can go to "contact", and view information regarding that topic).  However, the links with this code aren't working.  When I click on the different tabs, it does not show the corresponding page.

Comment: You're linking to the ID of the element by using `href="#contact"`. However, the element is set to `visible: hidden`? I suppose that you are missing some kind of third-party library to perform the tabbing navigation.

Comment: are these static web pages? you are linking to id's on the same page. You need to specify the file also.

Comment: I found the problem - I had to change it from 'visibility: hidden' to 'display: none', and then add '    document.getElementById("linkforcontact").addEventListener("click", function() {
        document.getElementById("contact").style.display = "block"
        document.getElementById("home").style.display = "none"
    })' to the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #333;
        }

        li {
            float: left;
        }

        li a {
            display: block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        li a:hover {
            background-color: #111;
        }

        li a:active {
            background-color: #51014d;
        }
        #home {
            background-color: honeydew;
        }
        #contact {
            background-color: lightblue;
        }
        #about {
            background-color: darkblue;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <ul>
        <li><a onclick="showDiv('home');" class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="showDiv('contact');" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a onclick="showDiv('about');" href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="home">
        <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="contact">
        <h2>you can reach me 
        at:</h2>
     </div>
     <div id="about">
        <h2>about us 
        at:</h2>
     </div>
    <script>
        function showDiv(id) {
            document.getElementById("home").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("about").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("contact").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        }

        showDiv('home');
   </script>
</body>

</html>
```